# Macros script Excel, filling in blanks with NULLS, error 400

Tags: excel, vba

All i'm trying to do is fill in NULL in the cells that are blank.

source code:

```
Sub fillNULLs()

Dim count As Integer
count = 0

Dim col As Integer
col = 2

While count < 23403

If (Cells(count, col) = "") Then

Cells(count, col) = "Null"

End If

count = count + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

---

I run the macros and i get a 400 and an okay button. Can anyone spot the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that count should be 1 at first before While loop

Comment: you were right, thats really odd to me but a useful learning experience for excel vb. First programming language i've seen to kick up a fuss at starting at 0 for a loop but thanks!

Comment: @Abstract Your way is not "VBAish". See my answer.

Comment: now it makes sense it was bugging because i was using the count for 0 when technically theres no row with index of 0, therefore causing the bug. Thanks Sjoo

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub fillNULLs()
Dim a, b As Range

Set a = Range("B1:B23402")
For Each b In a
   If (Trim(b.Value) = "") Then b = Null
Next b

End Sub
```

**Edit**

To check it is doing what it must do

```
Sub fillNULLs()
Dim a, b As Range

Set a = Range("B1:B23402")
For Each b In a
   If (Trim(b.Value) = "") Then b = "Null"
Next b  

End Sub
```

You will see "Null" in the modified values.

Comment: okay i thought it was good but you need to end the if statement and also all that happens is it lags and then does nothing but no 400 error which is a plus. But thanks anyway!

Comment: oh yeah okay, well my way now works but thanks for sharing :) yours does look nicer however mine gets the job done but thanks!

Comment: @Abstract This way is a much more flexible one, as you may select ANY range (rows, rectangular, disjoint, etc) without modifying the code. HTH